# How to allow access for CognitoIdentityProvider sdk in aws boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm attempting to write a small script that fetch my users details from aws cognito users pool. Although my boto3 SDK has access to my S3, Dynamodb etc', when attempting:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
response = client.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId='XXXXXX',
    Username='YYYYYY'
)
```

I get

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the AdminGetUser operation
```

But i can not find in the documentation how to allow such access for my SDK.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an IAM policy allowing the user (and consequently his/her access keys) or the resource (EC2, Lambda function, etc) to perform the `cognito-idp:AdminGetUser` operation. For example, a read-only policy for Cognito:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cognito-identity:Describe*",
        "cognito-identity:Get*",
        "cognito-identity:List*",
        "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
        "cognito-idp:Describe*",
        "cognito-idp:List*",
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```